# stl: priority_queue not sorting same priority elements in FIFO order

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, g++, priority-queue

I have the following code for C++ STL priority_queue implementation. But priority queues should arrange identical priority elements in FIFO order. However, the output of the code suggests differently. I am aware that priority queues internally depends on Heaps, and considering a heap the output is valid although it violates basic queue concept.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue> 

using namespace std; 

typedef struct data{
    int pri;
    char dat[30];

/*
    bool operator<(const data *rhs) const
    {
        return this->pri < rhs->pri;
    }
*/
}data_t;

struct compare{
    bool operator()(const data_t *ptr1, const data_t *ptr2) const
    {
        return ptr1->pri > ptr2->pri;
    }
};

void showpq(priority_queue <data_t*, vector<data_t*>, compare> gq) 
{ 
    priority_queue <data_t*, vector<data_t*>, compare> g = gq; 
    while (!g.empty()) 
    { 
        cout << "\n\t" << g.top()->dat; 
        g.pop(); 
    } 
    cout << '\n'; 
} 

int main () 
{ 
    data_t myList[10] = {{53, "Seqn: 0  Pri: 53"}, 
             {27, "Seqn: 1  Pri: 27"}, 
             {22, "Seqn: 2  Pri: 22"},
             {77, "Seqn: 3  Pri: 77"},
             {52, "Seqn: 4  Pri: 52"},
             {22, "Seqn: 5  Pri: 22"},
             {35, "Seqn: 6  Pri: 35"},
             {68, "Seqn: 7  Pri: 68"},
             {80, "Seqn: 8  Pri: 80"},
             {20, "Seqn: 9  Pri: 20"}};
    priority_queue <data_t*, vector<data_t*>, compare> gquiz; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
#if 0
        myList[i].pri = 1 + ( rand() % 100 );
        sprintf(myList[i].dat, "Val: %d\tPri: %d", i, myList[i].pri);
#endif
        gquiz.push(&myList[i]); 
    }

    cout << "The priority queue gquiz is : "; 
    showpq(gquiz); 

    cout << "\ngquiz.size() : " << gquiz.size(); 
    cout << "\ngquiz.top() : " << gquiz.top()->dat; 


    cout << "\ngquiz.pop() : "; 
    gquiz.pop(); 
    showpq(gquiz); 

    return 0; 
}
```

On building and executing the above code I see the following output:

```
The priority queue gquiz is :
        Seqn: 9  Pri: 20
        Seqn: 5  Pri: 22
        Seqn: 2  Pri: 22
        Seqn: 1  Pri: 27
        Seqn: 6  Pri: 35
        Seqn: 4  Pri: 52
        Seqn: 0  Pri: 53
        Seqn: 7  Pri: 68
        Seqn: 3  Pri: 77
        Seqn: 8  Pri: 80

gquiz.size() : 10
gquiz.top() : Seqn: 9  Pri: 20
gquiz.pop() :
        Seqn: 5  Pri: 22
        Seqn: 2  Pri: 22
        Seqn: 1  Pri: 27
        Seqn: 6  Pri: 35
        Seqn: 4  Pri: 52
        Seqn: 0  Pri: 53
        Seqn: 7  Pri: 68
        Seqn: 3  Pri: 77
        Seqn: 8  Pri: 80
```

From the above we see that:
`Seqn: 5` and `Seqn:2` both have priority as `22`, but `seqn: 2` is pushed before `Seqn: 5` of course. But during pop `seqn: 5` is popped before `Seqn: 2`. With varying data set sizes the order of `Seqn: 2` and `Seqn: 5` is unpredictable.

What is the way to preserve FIFO order with such a case and why is the behavior different?

Comment: Why dont you add the sequence number to the compare operation if prio is equal?

Comment: Priority queues don't usually maintain FIFO ordering among equal items.

Comment: Whatever gave you the idea that a priority queue has to maintain FIFO order for equal items? That is not in the definition of the [priority queue abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). If you want equal items to be sorted by insertion order, then you need a comparison function that will compare the sequence number if the keys are equal.

Comment: @JimMischel Using SN is a good solution except that we have to deal with its overflow. Using 64 bit SN is good but not the best because the overflow itself can occur, but apparently not in our age.